# Existence of map from a partition of the domain to the codomain of a surjective function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

As described in the title, I'm trying to prove the existence of a map from a partition $\mathscr F$ of the domain of a surjective function, made by all the preimages of the codomain, to each element of the codomain itself.

Let $f$ be a surjection from a set $A$ to a set $B$. For all $y\in B$ we have that $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is not empty. The family $\mathscr{F}=\{f^{-1}(\{y\}) : y\in B\}$ is made of disjoint sets, and exhausts $A$; thus $\mathscr F$ is a partition of $A$.

We know that for all $x_1, x_2\in A$, the following:
$$ \tag{1}\label{a} x_1 \sim x_2 \Leftrightarrow f(x_1) = f(x_2)$$
is the relation induced by $\mathscr F$ on $A$.

Let now $\tilde f : \mathscr F \to B : [x]\mapsto f(x)$. I'm trying to prove the existence of such a function; so I need to prove that:

> first: $\forall ([x_1], f(x_1))\in \tilde f, \forall ([x_2], f(x_2))\in \tilde f : f(x_1) \neq f(x_2) \implies [x_1] \neq [x_2]$
>
> second: $\forall [x] \in \mathscr F \exists f(x) \in B : \tilde f([x]) = f(x)$
>
> Or any equivalent statement.

For the first part: $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2) \implies [x_1] \neq [x_2]$ can be rewritten ($\ref{a}$) as $[x_1] = [x_2] \implies x_1 \sim x_2$, that is a tautology. $\Box$

I don't understand how to do the second one.
It's probably because I can't "relate" that $[x]$ "maps" to $f(x)$ with something else: can I say that $\tilde f([x]) = f(x) \Leftrightarrow x \in [x]$? And if i can, how can i derive this kind of information when it's gave to me a function defined by this type of laws?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think part of your problem with this is that it is poorly stated, in that it attempts to cut corners notation-wise. For someone who is well-versed in the theory, this is not an issue. The real meaning is understood. But for neophytes, these notational shortcuts - even when they understand the notation - lead to mental confusion when thinking about them.

So let me rephase it properly. And include something that you've left off:

To show that $\bar f : \mathscr F \to B : [x] \mapsto f(x)$ is a surjective function, one must show

1. That $\bar f$ is well-defined: if $\forall u\in \mathscr F, \forall x, y \in u, f(x) = f(y)$.
2. That $\bar f$ is a function: $\forall (u, b), (v, c) \in \bar f, b = c \implies u = v$.
3. That $\bar f$ is surjective: $\forall b \in B, \exists u \in \mathscr F : \bar f(u) = b$.

(1), which you didn't include, isn't hard to show, but it is necessary to do so before you can say that $\bar f$ even exists, much less is a surjective function. If $x \in u$, then $u = [x]$ and $y \in u \implies y\sim x$, i.e., that $f(x) = f(y)$.

(2) is the same as you've proven (though I phrased it in the contrapositive - just like you proved it).

(3) For this, we just go back to the fact that $f$ is surjective. That is, $\exists x \in A : f(x) = b$. But then $[x] \in \mathscr F$ and $\bar f([x]) = f(x) = b$.

Comment: Thank you! For showing that $\tilde f$ is well-defined (I maybe used the wrong term: "exists"), we need to show first that $\tilde f$ is defined for all elements in $\mathscr F$; I don't understand how to derive this from 1). In 2) I proved that $u = v \implies b=c$.

Comment: Yes, I aknowledged you proved $u = v \implies b=c$, What my comment on (2) meant was that your version of this statement was the contrapositive: $b \ne c \implies u \ne v$. (I prefer it stated forwards.) For (1), I suppose I took the same notational shortcut I railed against. The definition of $\bar f$ is actually "$\forall u \in \mathscr F, \bar f(u) = f(x)$ for some $x \in u$". For this definition to work - to provide a single value to $\bar f(u)$ - it is necessary that every $x \in u$ provide the same value. That is what it means to say $\bar f$ is well-defined, and what I proved in (1).

Comment: And as you can see, the definition applies to all $u \in \mathscr F$, so once it is seen that the definition works at all, it applies to all of $\mathscr F$.

Comment: In 2) $b=c \implies u=v$ is the converse of the contrapositive of my statement, not it stated forwards; why are they equivalent in this case? I found the definition of "well-defined function" [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Well-Defined) (my book doesn't provide this); Is it (should be?) equivalent to the general definition of mapping, for example to one of those given at this [link](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Mapping)? I should ask another question, because I think this is a more general one..

Comment: Nobody said anything about $b = c \implies u = v$. It has nothing to do with either your statements or mine. "Well-defined" is just a term indicating that the "definition" given actually works. It doesn't have a fixed meaning. I.e., it is a natural language jargon, not mathematical terminology. In this case, suppose that the sets in $\scr F$ were defined in such a way that $f$ did not have the same value on every member. Then would this same definition of $\bar f$ still make sense? No. In that case $\bar f$ would not be well-defined.

Comment: I am struggling on the definition of $\tilde f$ itself: there will always be an element $u\in \mathscr F$ such that $(u, f(x))$, for some $x\in u$, will be in $\tilde f$? This is the main question, the rest is okay:) I understood why there will be always a single value to $\tilde f$, but is true that this value exists for all the elements of the domain?

Comment: It is not that "there will always be an element $u$". Instead, it is "for every element $u$". By definition of $\scr F$, the elements $u \in \scr F$ are non-empty subsets of $A$. So we can define $\bar f = \{(u, f(x)) \mid u \in \mathscr F \text{ and }x \in u\}$. By that definition $\bar f$ has domain $\scr F$. Then either by (1) or (2) (when $\bar f$ is defined this way, they both say the same thing), we have $\bar f$ is a function.

Comment: Thank you, really! Perhaps there is a simple mistake on point 2) of your answer, as you pointed out above:)

Answer (score 0):

Let g = $\overline f.$  g maps [x] to f(x).  Is this a valid definition?
If [x] = [y], does g([x]) = g([y]) ie, does f(x) = f(y)?
Yes, but only because of particular equivalence relation used.
Thus g is well defined.